# How to get value of file element in form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have a form with some elements

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" id="validation-form" method="get">
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment[]" multiple />
<input type="text" id="greetings" name="greetings" required=""  />
```

on click of submit button i am calling

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#validation-form").serializeArray());
```

i get json like:
[{name:"greetings",value:"entered value"}]

how can i get the details of attachment[] element also. plz help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fileList = $("#attachment[]").get(0).files;
```

Keep in mind that files will return you an array of file elements from within the file API.

Check this great article for further info.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: i have to get the files separately using the above method , how can i get it when serializeArray() method is called

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you cannot use serializeArray() with file objects, as they are not part of the standard form post, they come on the multipart, while AFAIK serializeArray works over the form-data. However, files is already an array of file elements, you can just iterate over it and get each file separately. $("#attachment[]").get(0).files[0]; will return you the first file and so on.